# Persistent Internet Connectivity Issues on Lenovo Thinkpad E14 Gen3

Tags: windows-10, wireless-networking, drivers

I am experiencing persistent internet connectivity issues with my Lenovo Thinkpad E14 Gen3 (system version 20Y7003BUS) running Windows 10 22H2 November update. The problem started after installing the latest Windows Update, updating the BIOS through Lenovo Vantage (versions 1.15 and 1.16).

The connectivity issues are not limited to wireless; they also occur with the ethernet connection. On the same day, I installed VMware Player 17.5.0, which updated drivers for virtual network adapters related to VMware. I'm uncertain whether this is a contributing factor to the sudden onset of connectivity problems. I have upgrading Realtek RTL8852AE WiFi 6 802.11ax PCIe Adapter to driver version 6001.10.355.1. Additionally, I updated the Realtek PCIe Gbe Family Controller to version 10.68.815.2023, with both drivers sourced directly from the Realtek website, not Lenovo Vantage. What I also did was to reinstall Windows 10 to 2004 update. I did Windows Clean Start, with all unnecessary apps and services disabled.

Sometimes, my feeling is that when I let Laptop sit and I do nothing, connectivity is working, but when I start using the laptop, and do something on it, connectivity drops.

Has anyone else experienced similar issues with this combination of updates and driver installations? I'm seeking advice on troubleshooting steps or potential solutions to restore stable internet connectivity. If more details are needed, I'm happy to provide them.

System Information:

Laptop: Lenovo Thinkpad E14 Gen3

System Version: 20Y7003BUS

Windows Version: 10 22H2

BIOS Updates: 1.15 and 1.16

Realtek RTL8852AE WiFi 6 802.11ax PCIe Adapter Driver: 6001.10.355.1

Realtek PCIe Gbe Family Controller Driver: 10.68.815.2023

VMware Player Version: 17.5.0

Thank you for your assistance.

Comment: Run the Lenovo Diagnostics App to look for hardware errors, and if not, probably back up and reinstall Windows (to reset drivers and basic software)

Comment: Lenovo Diagnostics App shows no sign of hardware issues. 
I did one Win reinstall, but kept apps and data, it was not fully reset.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I read through the complete question again.

Lenovo Diagnostics did not show any hardware errors.

Windows Reset keeping Apps and Data also keeps the Windows User Profile.  It is possible that damage in the User Profile could cause the error you have.

Best course of action now is to fully back up, delete partitions and do a complete fresh install of Windows 10 to the current version.

Comment: I have seen all kind of things that User Profile can break but such issues I didn't so far, but I do not say that it is not possible, as I believe it is :) 
Will try fresh install, I cannot do much else. 
Thanks!

Comment: I did the procedure above described, and it really helped. The issue was quite possible caused by Windows User Profile.

Comment: I think so, which is why my suggestion

Comment: Very good guess! Thanks man!